# Generate CheckBoxList from a single column in MVC in .net

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, checkboxlist

I'm working on a HR project in MVC Entity Framework Database first.

My view that I've tried is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.emp_Disease, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
    <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-top:6px;margin:0px;">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Disease.Count(); i++)
        {
          @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Disease[i].emp_Disease)
          @Model.Disease[i].Name
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Disease[i].Name)
          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Disease[i].id)
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emp_Disease, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller action `HttpGet` is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Home(int id = 0)
{
    tbl_employee emp = new tbl_employee();
    emp.Disease = CheckDisease();
    if (id != 0)
    {
        using (hrm_DB db = new hrm_DB())
        {
            emp = db.tbl_employee.Where(m => m.emp_Id == id).FirstOrDefault<tbl_employee>();
        }
    }
    return View(emp);
}
```

And Model is:

```
public class Checkdisease
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool emp_Disease { get; set; }
}
```

List is:

```
public List<Checkdisease> Disease { get; set; }
```

My problem is to how generate CheckBoxList from a single database column?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your same scenario it is working.

> Model

```
public class tbl_employee
{
    public string emp_Disease { get; set; }
    public List<Disease> Disease { get; set; }
}

public class Disease
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool emp_Disease { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller

This action method will handle Get request, in this method we are going to fill List of Disease collection and send to view.

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {

        tbl_employee emp = new tbl_employee()
        {
            emp_Disease = "Disease1",
            Disease = new List<Disease>
            {
                new Disease { emp_Disease = false, id= 1,Name = "Disease1"},
                new Disease { emp_Disease = false, id= 2,Name = "Disease2"},
                new Disease { emp_Disease = false, id= 3,Name = "Disease3"},
                new Disease { emp_Disease = false, id= 4,Name = "Disease4"},
                new Disease { emp_Disease = false, id= 5,Name = "Disease5"},
            }

        };

        return View(emp);
    }
```

> Action Method Create Handling Post Request.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tbl_employee listdisease)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

> View

```
@{ Layout = null;}
@model WebApplication1.Models.tbl_employee
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.emp_Disease, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 " })
        <div class="col-md-10" style="padding-top:6px;margin:0px;">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Disease.Count(); i++)
            {
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Disease[i].emp_Disease)
                @Model.Disease[i].Name
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Disease[i].Name)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Disease[i].id)
                <br />
            }
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emp_Disease, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

> View in Browser

[image: Checkbox view]

> Debugging are POST request

[image]